# How to subset a pandas dataframe on value_counts?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename1.csv")

df
    column1  column2   column3
0        10       A          1
1        15       A          1
2        19       B          1
3      5071       B          0
4      5891       B          0
5      3210       B          0
6        12       B          2
7        13       C          2
8        20       C          0
9         5       C          3
10        9       C          3
```

Now, using the function `value_counts()` will give me the counts of each value in a certain column, e.g.

```
df.column3.value_counts()

1   3
2   2
3   2
```

However, I would like to subset a pandas dataframe based on the number of values in a given column. For example, in the above dataframe `df`, I would like to subset on rows with 3 or more unique values (excluding 0). In this case, the resulting dataframe would be

```
df
    column1  column2   column3
0        10       A          1
1        15       A          1
2        19       B          1
```

As the rows for values 2 and 3 only had two rows, i.e. 2, 3 only occurred twice in `column3`. What is the pandas way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby.filter`; In the filter, construct a unique boolean value for each group to filter the data frame:

```
df.groupby("column3").filter(lambda g: (g.name != 0) and (g.column3.size >= 3))
```

[image]

Another option could be:

```
df[(df.column3 != 0) & (df.groupby("column3").column3.transform("size") >= 3)]
```

Comment: Why is it `g.name`?

Comment: It's the key for the group, i.e, a unique value in `column3` in this case. You can also use `g.column3.iat[0]`. I just find it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could filter out the zeroes before you group:

```
 df1[df1['column3'] != 0].groupby("column3").filter(lambda x: x['column3'].size >= 3 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
In [132]: cnt = df.column3.value_counts()

In [133]: cnt
Out[133]:
0    4
1    3
3    2
2    2
Name: column3, dtype: int64

In [134]: v = cnt[(cnt.index != 0) & (cnt >= 3)].index.values

In [135]: v
Out[135]: array([1], dtype=int64)

In [136]: df.query("column3 in @v")
Out[136]:
   column1 column2  column3
0       10       A        1
1       15       A        1
2       19       B        1
```